# (Protractor e2e) Getting error "A Jasmine Spec timed out: Resetting WebDriver Control Flow"

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Hoping someone can help me out on this, as i've been searching around for days with no success

I'm currently attempting to use Protractor for e2e testing of an AngularJS application

I've got Protractor setup and running a test, however when I have more than one test / spec, the first test runs and then errors out with the following on the command line:

> A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
>   The last active task was: unknown

My config.js is as follows:

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js','fileupload.js'],
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
    isVerbose: true
  }
};
```

Here are both of my Jasmine tests

// spec.js

```
describe('Site login', function () {
    it('should login', function () {
        browser.driver.get('http://mysite.co.uk');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.name('UserName')).sendKeys('user');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.name('Password')).sendKeys('xpassword');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('logIn')).click();

        expect(browser.driver.findElement(by.id('topUsername')).getText()).toContain('user');

        browser.close();
    });
});
```

// File Upload spec

```
describe('File Upload', function() {
    it('should upload a file', function () {
        browser.driver.get('http://mysite.co.uk');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.name('UserName')).sendKeys('user');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.name('Password')).sendKeys('xpassword');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('logIn')).click();

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('upload')).click(); 
        browser.driver.findElement(by.name('FileToUpload')).sendKeys("C:\\myfile.csv"); 
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div/button[2]/span')).click(); 
        console.log('file has been uploaded');
        });
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

P.S apologies if I've formatted anything wrong, first time poster :)

**Edit**: Issue resolved by updating to Protractor v1.0.0 via npm update

Thanks a lot for everyone's help :)

Comment: try to disable this line browser.close(); You closed your test browser, then the next test doesnot have any browser to run.

Comment: Hi @NguyenVuHoang thanks alot for your reply, i've taken out the browser.closes() and am still seeing the same issue :(

Comment: do 3 files conf.js, fileupload.js and spec.js place at the same location? I've just try to re-run your scripts Finished in 1.799 seconds 2 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures

Comment: Yes, they are in the same location. Hmm that's really strange that you are able to run them and i'm not, do you get the Jasmine error message about Jasmine spec timed out?

Comment: nope :(, however, I deleted everything in your script content since I'm not able to access "http://mysite.co.uk".

Comment: ah this is mind boggling :( i'm using the latest version of protractor and running protractor config.js (after enabling the selenium standalone server)

Are you specs in two seperate files? Is there anything you've added in the tests to make the browser open a new instance perhaps for the second test?

Comment: are you also trying to do a file upload in your scenario? what's your version of protractor, my login test passes, but then I get the error about A Jasmine Spec Timed Out when the second test is about to run, and hence get a failure for that fileupload test

Comment: Is your test actually taking longer than 10 seconds? Maybe it's really timing out.

Comment: it seems to run really fast, less than 10 seconds for sure

Comment: i think it's better to answer your own question as how you solve it, and include [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) as resource for the future reader

Answer (score 1):

[refer to](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1978)      framework: 'jasmine2',

this to your protractor config
i've been having the same issue for days! lemme know if it helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion, we've since moved over to a java based framework with no Jasmine reporters, however I would bet this would fix the issue as long as protractor is updated to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

**You can add this code to your config file conf.js or otherName.js**

```
    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node
JasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    // if true, print colors to the terminal
    showColors: true,
    // if true display spec Name
    isVerbose: false,
    silent: true,
    // if true, include stack traces in failures
    includeStackTrace: true,
    // default time to wait in ms before a test fails
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
},
```

Comment: defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,